# How do you add motion in android studio for text views

Tags: android, animation, textview

I want to add motion to a block of text so that it enters from the right of the screen. is there any way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Animation to animate whole view, specifically `TranslateAnimation` to enter from right of the screen: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `transition` file. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionOrdering="together"
    android:duration="250">
    <slide android:slideEdge="right">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@id/toolbar" />
        </targets>
    </slide>
</transitionSet>
```

And then in the code where you start your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityHere.class);
ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions = 
        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
        new Pair<View, String>(viewHolder.mIconView, getString(R.string.detail_icon_transition_name)));
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Library for easy TextView animations  including left to right 
Link --> [Here](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView)

[image]
[image]
[image]

or programmatically a simple anim from X ---to------> X1(you can revert by changing values negative/positive),

Create an anim folder  res (new>directory)> anim

add a resource xml

move_it.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-3%p"
        android:toXDelta="30%p"
        android:duration="1200" />
</set>
```

and in your code

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_one);
textView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourActivityName.this, R.anim.move_it));
```

Comment: It says - The following classes could not be found com.hanks.htextview.Htextview

Comment: @K.A. Siddiqui well do you know how to use it ? 1. add the dependency in your gradle and sync it .. 2.Then you can use their custom XML ..in that you can give what anim type you want!! Read **usage** part that shows how to use it, it works like charm if you need a normal one you can use my code example

Answer (score 0):

How about a TextSwitcher, every time the text change, then the animation happens.

```
<TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/txtSwitcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in your code:

```
TextSwitcher switcher = (TextSwitcher)findViewById(txtSwitcher);
    switcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            TextView t = new TextView(ActivityClass.this);
            //do other stuff the suit your needs
            return t;
        }
    });

    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    switcher.setInAnimation(in);
    switcher.setOutAnimation(out);
```

If you do switcher.setText("new text") then the animation happens.